# Why smartctl doesn't show the reallocated sectors count?

Tags: linux, smartctl

I have the smartctl query prepared before by my collegaues.

```
smartctl -d ata -a {disk_name} | awk '/Reallocated_Sector_Ct/{print $10}'
```

I'm trying to use the query, but it prints nothing.
The `smartctl -d ata -a {disk_name}` query output has no `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` field.
How to know if this field doesn't exist for the disk should not have that or I make wrong query?

Comment: Are you getting any output at all, or is only the Reallocated_Sector_Ct missing? Because a common reason to not get any [smart data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology) is when  you are not querying a real disk and for example **a logical drive** managed by a proper hardware RAID controller (which requires using a vendor specific approach to monitor the health of the underlying real disks that make up the virtual drive) or **a virtual disk** presented by a hypervisor to a VM or a **NVME** that measures "spare capacity" rather than bad sectors?

Comment: @HBruijn
I got the advice - thanks to colleagues - and the correct is
`smartctl -a /dev/sda -d cciss,0`
the query above prints the result that I expected.
For now still trying to understand all that magic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct query I got is
`smartctl -a /dev/sda -d cciss,0`

Still trying to understand how does it work, but it does.

So the final version would be

`smartctl -a /dev/sda -d cciss,0 | awk '/Reallocated_Sector_Ct/{print $10}'`

Answer (score 2):

> How to know if this field doesn't exist for the disk should not have that or I make wrong query?

Without knowing what kind of "disk" you're trying to monitor it is difficult to know if you're making a wrong query or not.

There are several common scenario's:

- The disk does not support [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology) at all.
  In that case I'd expect that `smartctl` gives you an appropriate warning and.or error message.
  Several common causes as to why a "disk" won't support SMART:

  1. Your host is a VM and the "disk" is a virtual disk presented by a hypervisor and the virtual driver doesn't emulate (irrelevant) [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology) data
  2. This disk is not a real disk but a logical drive managed by a (proper hardware) RAID controller (which requires using a vendor specific approach to monitor the health of the underlying real disks that make up the virtual drive)
- The disk does support [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology) :

  1. but the `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` is simply not presented by the disk firmware.
     For example [NVME drives have specific SMART attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology#Known_NVMe_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) for tracking ***spare capacity***, which is equivalent to but also different from the Reallocated_Sector_Ct
  2. [`smartctl`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/smartctl) is not detecting the device type correctly and you need to give it a hint to use the correct "driver" with a `-d TYPE, --device=TYPE` flag.

And possibly others.

---

Based on your comment that you're using `smartctl -d cciss,0 /dev/sda` :

Take a look at the [`smartctl` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/smartctl)

```
cciss,N - [FreeBSD and Linux only] the device consists of one or more 
          SCSI/SAS or SATA disks connected to a cciss RAID controller. 
          The non-negative integer N (in the range from 0 to 15 
          inclusive) denotes which disk on the controller is monitored.

To look at disks behind HP Smart Array controllers, use syntax such as:

smartctl -a -d cciss,0 /dev/cciss/c0d0    (cciss driver under Linux)

          This will give the smart information about the first physical 
          disk drive (0) connect to the controller at /dev/cciss/c0d0 . 
          (Disk drive numbering is 0 based)

smartctl -a -d cciss,1 /dev/sg2    (hpsa or hpahcisr drivers under Linux)
          This will give the SMART information about the second physical
          disk drive (1) connected to the controller at /dev/sg0
```

If that doesn't work that makes me think you might be mixing two things: you're addressing `/dev/sda` which might be the logical drive, rather than a specific disk attached to a HP Smart Array controller. The correct syntax to address a specific drive depends on which driver your system is using: [`cciss`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/cciss.4.html) or [`hpsa`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/hpsa.4.html)